# PowerShell unlock/unload imported CSV

Tags: csv, powershell

Morning,

I guess the question is in the title. I have one script that runs though a folder structure importing CSV's, works with each one then tries to delete them when finished.
Sadly a lot of these lock to PowerShell and the only way I can remove them is to close PS.

Is there any way of unloading a csv?
I found another thread on here that suggest $IMPORT.dispose() but all I get is :

```
Method invocation failed because [System.Management.Automation.PSCustomObject] does not contain a method named 'Dispose'.
```

Any help would be appreciated. 
Thanks

@beatcracker

I can't think of anything else that would lock them, they're generated via a logon script and not opened by anything other than PowerShell.
This is what I get, not sure if I've got the context right?

```
Write-Host $(& 'handle.exe' '\\fileshare\CDRIVE\user1\user1SEARCH.csv' )
www.sysinternals.com No matching handles found.

Move-Item '\\fileshare\CDRIVE\user1\user1SEARCH.csv' "$PST_PARENT\"
Move-Item : The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process. 
At line:1 char:1 + Move-Item '\\fileshare\CDRIVE\user1\user1SEARCH.csv...
```

@VinceG

```
$IMPORT_TOTAL_CSV = Import-Csv "$PST_PARENT\DailyReports\1) DiscoveryCollective\Search Report Total.csv"
$ALL_CSV | foreach { $IMPORT_EACH_CSV = Import-Csv $_ }
```

@alroc

Apologies, still getting used to StackOverFlow

Comment: I doubt that PS is locking CSV files, because `Import-CSV` reads them entirely to memory. Try adding `Write-Host $(& 'handle' 'c:\path\to\file.csv')` before code that tries to delete the file. This will show you what process has lock on it. You can get Handle [here](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896655.aspx).

Comment: Excuse me @Graham, how (which method) do yo use to open or import your csv file ?

Comment: @GrahamJordan your code should be in the original post, not in comments where it's very difficult to read.

Comment: @GrahamJordan, were you able to get this resolved? If so, can we get the accepted answer?

Comment: @DBADon - Neh, was never resolved. Think I just ended up running a clean up script a day or so after. Can be closed.