# Import-Csv locks file in PowerShell ISE

Tags: powershell, powershell-4.0

I want to read some CSV files with PowerShell and then save them in the same spot with a different delimiter:

```
$content = (import-csv -path $filepath -Encoding utf8 -Delimiter ",") 
write-host $(& ..\DLLs\Handle\handle.exe $filepath)
remove-item $filepath
export-csv ...
```

I fails at the deleting the file step.
I have added the handle.exe Debug information as suggested in [PowerShell unlock/unload imported CSV](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35288294/powershell-unlock-unload-imported-csv) and it indeed shows that the powershell_ise.exe still has a handle on the file. When the script finishes, I can delete or rename it as I wish.

How to get around this?

Answer (score 1):

Try to *omit*  the `Remove-Item` cmdlet since its probably not necessary. The `Import-CSV` cmdlet shouldn't lock the file and I can't reproduce that. However, you could try to use the `Get-Content` to read the file and pipe it to the `ConvertFrom-Csv` cmdlet (note: you don't need to explicit specify the delimiter for a comma separated CSV):

```
$content = Get-Content $filepath -raw | ConvertFrom-Csv
```

Comment: Just exporting without removal doesn't work. And using `Get-Content` in conjunction with `ConvertFrom-CSV` does neither. I agree that it shouldn't lock and I believe I have seen it behave differently before/on a different system. That's what I have here though. Wait... was using ISE x86, on the 64 Bit version it works. Does that make any sense? P.S. Export-CSV complains when the file exists

Comment: Strange. Try use the `-force` parameter on the `Export-CSV` cmdlet.

Comment: Upon closer inspection I can't keep my claim up, that it worked in the 64 Bit version. Don't want to lead anyone astray here. The `-force` parameter also doesn't help, seems as if it needs to be removed.

Answer (score 1):

I got it now. My particular setup, that part, which I had omitted, because I didn't think it was necessary, was the culprit.

The above code was running within a pipeline, part of which was searching in the file for a certain text

```
ls *.csv | select-string "someText" | % { do the CSV Stuff }
```

What was locking then, was the select-string command, not the import-csv.